# Implementing Queueing in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a simple WCF service which creates a directory at a location specified as a param.
The service is hosted as a Windows service and runs under the administrator account.

The InstanceContextMode is Single and so is the Concurrency.

The method returns a string of the directory location after creating it.

A client is accessing this service from another computer using ASP.NET.
He has a use case, he clicks the button on the page multiple times in a matter of few seconds, like clicking it 5 times in 2 seconds. What's happening is that the service creates only 2 or 3 folders not all 5.

I know that there is a default queueing mechanism in WCF and for my service it's either not working or I haven't written it to use that mechanism.

How do I go about solving this problem.

Here's the ASP.NET code for button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientClass objClientClass = new ClientClass();

    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    Random random = new Random();

    string uid = random.Next().ToString();
    returnValue = objClientClass.StartWorkflow(uid);
    Label1.Text = returnValue;

}
```

Here's the app.config of the host:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
               switchValue="All"
               propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" />
    </listeners>
   </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
               switchValue="All"
               propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="Traces.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>

</system.diagnostics>  
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"></compilation>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                  logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
                  logMalformedMessages="true"
                  maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                  maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentSessions="5" maxConcurrentInstances="5" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" name="Utilities.WS.SampleWebService.Jobs">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        contract="Utilities.WS.SampleWebService.IJobs" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add     baseAddress="http://00.00.000.00:8732/Utilities.WS.SampleWebService.Jobs" />
      </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Regards.

Comment: Enable tracing in your service and see how many messages did your service recieved. Then you would understand, weather the problem is on your asp side or on WCF side

Comment: Hi @voo, I enabled the tracing. The svcLog shows that the service recieved only 3 requests from the 5 clicks and I can see the results of the 3 requests. So what happened to the remaining 2?

Comment: It seem to me that the problem is not in your service. Can it be in your Button1_Click handler? I mean that you can click it 5 times, but it fires only 3 times. And try to change your MaxConcurrentCalls in your throttling (number of calls on the service that are currently executing)

Comment: Hi @voo, thanks for your help. It is the client that's at fault. The request need's to be validated on that end. Thanks again for suggesting tracing, appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1. ping from client (Which is server side ASP.NET code, not the browser), can it reach the machine hosting the WCF service? Firewall sitting between your webserver and where WCF is hosted?

STEP 2. SVC log
Setup svclog from your config file,

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Then use SvcTraceViewer from command prompt - look for red.

STEP 3. Add some more logging to your operation and see if anything actually executed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx